# changing factors to numeric - how to cope with unavailable values

Tags: r, spss, missing-data, r-factor

I have a big data set from a questionary. Importing it from SPSS to R (using SPSS's Stata-Output) gave me the answer to each question as factor.

A question has answers from 1 to 10. However, there are a lot of missing values. R recoginzes them aswell.

However, now I'd like to do some calculations - for example I want to calculate the mean of an answer (not very good statistics, I know, never mind).

So I have to make recode the factors to numerics. I did this with `as.numeric()`.

However, now I have missing values encoded as 11 to 14. Of course I can't calculate any mean like this.

What would be the proper way to recode factors as numerics and tell R to set any value bigger than 10 to NA?

Example:
Do you like fish?

```
    not at all                   very much | don't know  no answer  don't tell
R:  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10 |     11          12         13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't need the missing values, I'd do something like:

```
a[a>10] <- NA
```

Then, you can use:

```
mean(a, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Alternately, if you want to work around those missing values, you can just use:

```
mean(a[a<=10])
```

Comment: another possibility (just so you know): Assuming 'a' is the data.frame and 'fish' is the name of the variable you want to change, just use: a$fish = ifelse(a$fish>10, NA, a$fish).

Answer (score 4):

Let's call your data frame `data` (you might want to take a copy first). The following would set all values greater than 10 in all columns to `NA`:

```
data[data>10]<-NA
```

The above assumes you've already applied `as.numeric`.

Comment: thanks a lot! I never used the left side of a variable definition yet. very interesting :)